# Backup to nul using Ola Hallengren Maintenance Solution

Tags: backup, ola-hallengren

Is backup to `@Directory = nul` supported using Ola Hallengren's Backup Maintenance Solution?

I tried this, but got errors.

Please advise.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Are you doing some kind of backup performance testing on a development environment?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What errors do you get?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't answerwed the questions asking you to explain exactly what it is you want to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ola Hallengren's backup script does not support backing up a database and/or transaction log to a `Nul` device/directory.

You might want to ask him to add this feature in a future release.

Both `'Nul'` and `'''Nul'''` result in the following error message:

> ```
> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Server NB31710, Procedure DatabaseBackup, Line 592  
> The value for the parameter @Directory is not supported.
> ```

Note that the latest version of Hallengren's script (as at 1 Jul 2019) does allow you to backup up to NUL. The use case for this at my company is to pretend to backup non-prod so that the transaction logs act as in production - that is, we don't change dbs to SIMPLE recovery and we don't get developers calling us up saying that the transaction log has filled up.

Comment: If *I* wrote a utility that did backups, I'd purposely deny the ability to backup to `NUL:` since  someone somewhere will run backups like that and expect to restore them.

Comment: @MaxVernon +1 - love the comment :-) - now they're on Linux, maybe we'll have posters wanting to go to /dev/null as well - a Black Hole storage engine for SQL Server if you will!

Comment: Another use case is when you need FULL recovery mode for mirroring or availability groups, so you need to take log backups to keep the log file size down, but you have no use for the log backup files as they would never be used - e.g. in some data warehouse situations where you can easily reload data from source.